# Calculating bounding box coordinates based on center and radius

Tags: coordinate-system

I need to calculate a bounding box for osm query. I get coordinates of center of the area (WGS84) and radius (meters).

How can I do it?

I though about using some kind of projection, calculating projected box coordinates and then convert it back.

Is it good idea?

If so, which projection will suit the best to this task?

I've read that miller's projection is a poor idea and it's better to use state plane projection. But on the other hand in my case bounding box doesn't need to be accurate. The most important for me is to calculate those coordinates quickly.

Can you show me some code example that do conversions essential for calculating bounding box?

I wanted to make this works on whole planet, but if there are better approximations I can assume that it should work in Eastern Europe:

```
Latitude: 48.342 - 55.279
Longitude: 13.645 - 25.071
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming accuracy is unimportant, then if

- your centre is `(X, Y)`,  where `Y` is latitude, `X` is longitude, in degrees
- your original search radius is `r`, and
- the earth radius is `R`, in the same units as `r`

Then the bounding box corners are simply `(X - dX, Y - dY)` and `(X + dX, Y + dY)` where

`dY = r * C / 360`,  the "search radius", as difference in latitude, where

- `C = 2 * pi * R`,  is the earth circumference,

`dX = dY * cos (rad (Y))`,  the "search radius", as difference in longitude.

Comment: Please note: until yesterday, this answere was incorrect wrt dY

Answer (score 2):

Having radius in kilometers and given that in one latitude degree there is always 111.11 km, one may use following:

```
dY = r / 111.11;
dX = dY / cos(rad(Y));
```

I would think that this should be the same as in Martin's answer, but apparently `1/(360/R) == 17.6972` (for kilometers) so it looks wrong. I was using the suggested formula for years without any issues.

Comment: I have corrected my equation one more time -- should now agree with yours!

Answer (score 1):

If you do wish to do a lot of accurate and fast planar cogo (coordinate geometry) calculations, then transforming your geographic coordinates (you have WGS84 coordinates) using a [**conformal map projection**](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjConf/projConf.html) first would be a good idea.

As you say, [Miller's projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_cylindrical_projection) is poor (it is *not* conformal) and "*state plane*" projections (they *are* conformal) are good candidates. However, "*state plane*" is really just an American term for the accepted standard conformal projection for a particular US state. So, it's better to think about any appropriate conformal projection -- the most common being [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) -- for your area of interest.

And remember a universal truth about projections: the further away one gets from the "central" point or line for that projection, the greater is the geometric distortion.

- [List of map projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you recommend conformal projections for this kind of work?  (In principle, the projection to minimize the errors in these distance calculations will always be non-conformal.)

Comment: @whuber: I was commenting on general planar cogo calcs. I think surveyors use conformal projections due to their properties of always preserving angles and, while distance *is* distorted, its distortion at any given point is the same in all directions. I don't know of any formal explanation as to why those properties suit cogo, but it does seem intuitive -- cogo involving angles and distances. Could be an interesting, separate question!

Comment: @whuber: The problem with distance-preserving projections is that they only work (preserve scale) in one direction, such as N-S in a cylindrical equidistance projection, or, in all directions but from only one point, such as in an azimuthal equidistance projection.